# OData schema generator for Django (CSDL)

Tags: django, django-models, odata, edmx, csdl

Is there an existing library to generate CSDL documents (optionally wrapped in EDMX) from Django models? The end goal is for use in an OData provider.

CSDL: http://www.odata.org/media/30002/OData%20CSDL%20Definition.html#csdl12.1

Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541140(v=prot.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not much help to you now, but for posterity, you could look at the [Pyslet](http://www.pyslet.org) Odata2 Python module. The author discusses using it with Django [here](http://swl10.blogspot.com/2014/05/adding-odata-support-to-django-with.html)

Comment: Wow. :) Looks like it has good support for the CSDL, too. http://pyslet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/odatav2_csdl.html